# underline after h2

Tags: css

I really don'know how to add an underline after a headline!

what is the best way to css the example below?

H2_**__**

lorem lorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you mean below a `<h2>` then just adding a `border-bottom:1px solid red` in your CSS should suffice.

if you mean after the heading text, then try this:

HTML

```
<h2 class="underline"><span>lorem ipsum</span></h2>
```

CSS

```
h2.underline { padding-right:20px; border-bottom:1px solid red; position:relative; }
h2.underline span { display:block; border-bottom:1px solid white; position:absolute; bottom:-1px } /*border color must be same as background color. assumed here to be white*/
```

Another approach that will work for browsers that support `:after` is to generate the "*_*" with CSS.

See both examples here: http://jsbin.com/uyoda5/2

Comment: thanks Moin and all the other...this solutions works for me :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any way to do this without adding markup.

```
<h2>Lorem Ipsum<span class="post-h2"></span></h2>
```

And then:

```
.post-h2 {
    padding-left: 2em; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid black; 
}
```

Comment: your example won't work. `padding` cannot be applied on an inline element such as a `<span>`, without first giving it a `display:block;`

Comment: You're confusing `padding` with `margin`. You can give padding to an inline element. That's why I chose that.

Comment: @Moin - `display:inline-block;` will allow you to use an inline type element but with block-level features, so you can get around this kind of problem.

Comment: only padding-left and padding-right will have an effect on inline elements. see: http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/

Comment: Yes, but again, that's why I used `padding-left`. This example is quite solid and functional.

Comment: Yes, it does work, but the empty `<span>` would trouble purists

Answer (score 1):

You could try using CSS's `:after` feature (though I haven't seen it used for this sort of thing before):

```
h2:after {
    content: ' ';
    border-bottom:solid black 1px; /* using border rather than underline; it's easier that way */
    width:20px; /*however long you want the underline */
    display:inline-block; /* this is required for the width parameter to work */
}
```

As I say, I haven't seen `:after` used this way before, but I've just tested the above code and it worked for me, at least in Firefox.

However note that it definitely *won't* work in older versions of IE, so if you need a 100% cross-browser solution, you may have to do something else (which basically means adding extra markup).

This page has more info about `after`: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/beforeafter.html

Comment: in this example 'content' can be also an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

On modern browsers you should be also able to do this, without useless extra markup

```
  h2:after {
    color: black;
    content: "___" 
  }


 <h2>Test</h2>
```